# Java awt applet with Microsoft JVM white screen

Tags: java, applet, awt

I have a java chat applet that's compatible with JDK1.1 so it works well even with Microsoft JVM.

the thing is, sometimes the chat area within the applet becomes white and messed up. 
It can only be fixed back by closing the whole Internet Explorer (all windows and tabs) and restarting it.

this doesn't exist when running the applet on sun's JVM, but we have to use MS's.
it seems like it's related to the instance of JRE that runs with the browser when the first applet starts.

The area that becomes messed up is a panel object used to render users's chat text.
Any ideas?

Comment: You do know that the Microsoft implementation reach its end of service life on 30 June 2009? http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/java/default.mspx

Answer (score 0):

In perhaps a related matter, Java 5 is End Of Life this month.

You may find you have to use something which can be supported like Java 6, or a non-Java solution.
Perhaps an open source Ajax chat...